# Mac OS X server - git access, fix repositories permission

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, osx-server

I've tried to install gitlab on my Mac OS X Server, in one step I needed to run script which changed permission of the repository. With this, I have lost limited access to git, now all user can access repository. When I look in permissions in Server.app, it show only user that should access the git.

The git rep shows this permissions: Existing: drwxrws---+, newly created and limited to show only to Admins: drwxrwx---+ (but still downloaded by regular user).

Any advice how to fix this ?

Thank you,

Comment: The "+" indicates that there is also an access control list for the file, and this is probably what allows other users access. Use `ls -le` to show the ACL as well as the regular permissions.

Comment: Gordon: thank you for tip. I see only users that should access the rep.:
drwxrwxrwx+ 10 _teamsserver  _www  340 26 črv 11:54 App_android.git
 0: group:admin allow list,add_file,search,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 1: user:custom user allow list,add_file,search,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown,file_inherit,directory_inherit